# Stop postback on TextChanged

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, postback, validation

I have a textbox in an aspx page that has a TextChanged event attached to it.
I also have a validator attached to the textbox.

When the text is changed, the validate triggers but in case there is an error the textchanged event is still called. Do you know if it's possible to stop the postback on textchanged if the validator fires?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ontextchanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqQuantity" ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" runat="server" ErrorMessage="The quantity is mandatory."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move validation to client side adding `EnableClientScript="true"` attribute. Postback won't occur as check will be performed with JS.

Other than that you can check whether page is valid when performing callback function for TextChanged event so that to define whether function can proceed. You should add `ValidationGroup` attribute to your validator and call `Page.Validate` function specifying that group before `Page.IsValid` is checked.

**Upd**

Here's the tip.

Add your own JS function, e.g.:

```
function IsValid( args ) {
        if( args.value.length == 0 ) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

In `Page_Load` event add this code:

```
txtQuantity.Attributes[ "onchange" ] = "if ( IsValid(this) == false ) return;";
```

This won't mess up auto postback when input is correct, but will prevent postback otherwise.

Comment: You are right, and I tried this. The thing is I have a RangeValidator which needs a Min and Max values, and I'm having problems sending those two values into the IsValid function. But your idea works.
For that reason I'm going to accept your answer although the problem is not solved..

Comment: You still can back client side scenario up.
For that purpose add page-level variable on server side, then in server mark-up right smth like:

var MinValueStr = "<%= MinValue %>";

and convert it into integer before use.

Comment: That wouldn't work because the textbox is in a List control, I need specific Min and Max values per row in the list, but I think I overcame it. I'll share when finished.

Comment: What if someone disables JavaScript in their browser?

Answer (score 4):

Add `CausesValidation="true"` for the text box and it will be good. If the validation is not valid there won't be any post-back.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ontextchanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Yeah but this avoids postback and I want to have AutoPostback = "true" so it can validate the data inside the textbox for other logic in the program.

Comment: Thank you Naveen. It does what it is supposed to do. Wonderful!

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing an inline, shorter version of the accepted answer:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server"
    AutoPostBack="true" ontextchanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged"
    onchange="if (this.value.length == 0) return;"></asp:TextBox>
```

Having the same problem with a RequiredFieldValidator, the above worked for me.

Known nag: the designer complains that "onchange" is not a valid server-side attribute.

Answer (score 0):

try it after change AutoPostBack="true" as AutoPostBack="false"..

Comment: And how is my TextChanged event going to postback then? :s

Comment: Why you want to postback on textchanged event..is there business logic attached with it?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is in my client validation function I test the event type I am in. If the event shows me in a change event, I claim the validation passed and leave.

```js
  if (event.type === 'change') {
   args.IsValid.true;
      return;
  }
```

I believe this is the best solution as you can leave the validator wired up and the textbox set as you like and no longer worry about the change event causing the validation.