# Stop Postback if Validation Error

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, validation

I have the following text box control ;

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="85px" class="validate[ERExpenseTypeDaterequired,custom[float]]"
                                OnTextChanged="txtAmount_TextChanged"   ></asp:TextBox>
```

Here, if there any value change in the text box , `txtAmount_TextChanged` will be called because `AutoPostBack="true"` is there in the control.

So if we put a non numeric value in the textbox, validation error will fire from the attribute Class using Jquery, but this error which pops up as a red box from the textbox wont stays for more than 3 seconds, it vanishes when the page posts back within 3 seconds, This post back is happening just because there is a `AutopostBack="true"`.

I cannot do `Autopostback="false"` because, I need to do some calculation based on this text box value change on the spot.

If I do `Autopostback="false"`, page will not post back and error message stays for ever, but I cannot do any calculations on "`txtAmount_TextChanged`" event as this event will never be called on textchcange if `Autopostback="false"`.

So, what I do to prevent this postback, if there is any validation error in this textbox?

Comment: use `java script` for calulation on textbox

Comment: Your problem looks similar to the below question



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524492/stop-postback-on-textchanged

Comment: No there is no required field validator in my case

Comment: Krunal .. that we can do it on least priority...if nothing else works

Comment: See Answer from Naveen at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524492/stop-postback-on-textchanged ... basically add CausesValidation="true" for the text box, better explained there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a client-side event handler, and return false from it when you don't want a PostBack to happen.

```
<asp:TextBox onkeydown="return doMyCheck()" ID="txtAmount" runat="server"
  AutoPostBack="true" Width="85px" class="validate[ERExpenseTypeDaterequired,custom[float]]"
  OnTextChanged="txtAmount_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

JavaScript:

```
function doMyCheck() {
  if (// call your jQuery validity check) 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: oops u didnt see ... i updated in ur answer only now it is not visible

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected... this the error

Comment: And this comes from the line :                             <input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_812dd644_c15e_4f29_b484_62dee31b34ee$ctl00$ReportExpenseControl$gdvReportExpense$ctl02$txtAmount" type="text" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_812dd644_c15e_4f29_b484_62dee31b34ee_ctl00_ReportExpenseControl_gdvReportExpense_ctl02_txtAmount" class="validate[ERExpenseTypeDaterequired,custom[float]]" onkeydown="return doMyCheck()" style="width:85px;" />

Comment: onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_812dd644_c15e_4f29_b484_62dee31b34ee$ctl00$ReportExpenseControl$gdvReportExpense$ctl02$txtAmount\',\'\')', 0)"

Comment: did you add `function doMyCheck()` to your JavaScript (i.e. between `<script>` tags?

Comment: Yes i do added a function with similar name

Answer (score 2):

```
function txtAmount_TextChanged(){
    //do validations here, Eg: validate if txtAmount is valid amount and "> 0"
   return false; //if somethings's wrong, else true

}
```

Comment: where i need to place/call the above function? HTML or code behind?

Comment: @PeteEngineer: In the relevant `script` tags in your aspx page or in a linked js file `<script scr="hello.js".. />`.

Comment: txtAmount_TextChanged is a serverside function i have writtedn in codebehind...  are you saying i need to write a client side function in same name?

Comment: @PeteEngineer: Yes there needs to be *some* client-side function. Choose any name of your liking.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Input` event to check the added text in Textbox using jquery

```
jQuery('#txtAmount').live('input', function() 
   {
     // do your Validation 
     // If Valid return True
     // If Invalid Return False
   }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery change function

```
$('#txtbox').change(function() { if(validationfail){return false;} );
```

you can use keychange event also

```
 $('#txtbox').keyup(function() { 
       if(validationfail){return false;} 
    });
```